# Liferay Service for Business Logics

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to clear one doubt. I am creating my own service class to manipulate data. Should i create this service instance at class level(in MVCPortlet) or create new instance in my processAction/doView method. 
Is there is any issue of thread safety while using instance level.

Fg:

```
public class MvcCycle extends MVCPortlet {

    int counter;
    LdapService ldapservice;

    @Override
    public void init() throws PortletException {
        counter=0;
        ldapservice = new LdapService(); // Option 1
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Counter hits "+ ++counter);
        // 
        LdapService ldapservice = new LdapService(); // Option 2
        ldapservice.authUser(request.getParameter("email"));
        // -- some code--
        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Last counter "+counter);
        counter=0;
        super.destroy();
    }

}

    class LdapService{
         public boolean authUser(String email){
              if(//logic to authenticate user){
                   return true;
              }else{
                   return false;
              }
         }
    }
```

Here, my ldapservice initiate only once. So when multiple hits come. which code is beneficial on this time either Option1 or Option 2.

Hope i have cleared my problem.

Comment: Why not define service class using service builder and customize as per your implementation.

Comment: +1 to use ServiceBuilder. Another option is to remove it: Your sample code doesn't use it at all, thus it's quite meaningless.

Comment: HI, This service is not for DB interaction. It will be used for data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on your comment: in general: it depends. We don't have enough information to give you blank architectural recommendations.

In the context of Liferay it could make sense to utilize service builder, even if you don't have database interaction. Just create an empty entity, you'll have a service with no persistence.

```
<entity name="MyService" local="true"/>
```

That's it. Now implement MyServiceLocalServiceImpl added you're done

Edit, after your clarification: it doesn't make a difference. I'd still recommend to *not* instantiate at all in your portlet, because that makes your portlet dependent on the service implementation. E.g. I still go with service builder.

You're also asking about thread safety and that depends on your implementation as well. Your sample code is thread safe, but the actual code might not be. Your judgement.

Comment: Thank you Olaf, I just want to create my own service layer to manipulate data or some business logic. I have my own service builder service in my project, but i don't want to do that code in these services.

Comment: In that case you're not giving enough information in your question. In fact after your content I still don't have a clue of your intent and acceptance criteria

Comment: I have updated the question. Please give me your valuable advice. Thanks